# UITableView shows always 15 rows

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have wrote a tableViewController and set in the storyboard as per all tutorials around.
Now I have created a very basic array with 31 elements but the result is that only 15 elements are shown, even if the array count returns the correct number of elements.
Here the simple code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"5:10 am", @"5:45 am", @"6:45 am", @"7:10 am",
                    @"7:30 am", @"7:45 am", @"8:00 am", @"8:15 am",
                    @"8:30 am", @"9:05 am", @"9:40 am", @"10:15 am",
                    @"10:45 am", @"11:15 am", @"11:45 am", @"12:15 pm",
                    @"12:45 pm", @"1:15 pm", @"1:45 pm", @"2:15 pm", @"2:45 pm",
                    @"3:15 pm", @"3:45 pm", @"4:15 pm", @"5:20 pm", @"6:20 pm",
                    @"7:15 pm", @"8:15 pm", @"9:15 pm", @"10:15 pm", @"11:15 pm", nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [myArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"foo";
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Even If I set the number of rows manually to 4 for example, I see for rows with the correct array element but 11 empty rows... for a total again of 15 rows. 
Any idea?

ps: It looks like only "1 page" is displayed in the iOS simulator... like no scroll is possible, but the array is for sure filled up with all the elements ...

Comment: What happens in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`? Can you set a breakpoint and print the value of `[myArray count]`?

Comment: In first case, scroll down. Second Case, it's not a bug. Both case you can handle using setting the height of rows that you need to see on screen.

Comment: [myArray count] returns the correct number... but it looks like only one page is displayed in the iOS simulator....

Comment: Within the interface builder, select your tableview and look at the attributes panel on the RHS. Make sure the box for 'Scrolling enabled" has been ticked. It should be by default, though you may have unticked this by mistake?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the result?

Comment: May be Autolayout issue check that and try to reload the tableview data

Answer (score 0):

Your cod is totally perfect . it seems that in storyboard you are not set proper properties of table view. thats why you are only able to show 15 row in table view.
so Goto(Storyboard->your tableview's view ->) sizeInspector -> set auto resizing property with all red marked arrow.

Answer (score 0):

The Tableview is tricky to scroll down on in the simulator. Had the same issue myself.  What I did was left-clicked on the Magic mouse and held the click down and then moved the mouse itself "Up" to bring in the rest of my numbers.  Hope that helps